# Table reference does not show the word 'Table'

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I'm trying to refer to a table in my report, but the reference wouldn't include the word 'Table' as follows. Any ideas why? :) [image]

The LaTeX code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
The figures is listed in \ref{table:1}
\begin{table}[!ht] \centering
\caption{This is a table \label{table:1}} 
\begin{tabular}{c | c}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 \\ \hline
A & 1 \\
B & 2 \\
C & 3 \\
D & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome, this is the default and to be expected. You can use package `hyperref` along with the `\autoref` command.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Write Table in your text or use package `cleverref` ...

Comment: btw, package `booktabs` provides some useful commands and hints in the doc on typesetting tables. Package `caption` cn help you in aligning the caption. ;-)

Comment: Use `listed in Table~\ref{table:1}`.